# Existence of an independent binomial random variable

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, binomial-distribution

This question is motivated by my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3387738/solve-p2-leq-x-leq-4-p3-leq-y-leq-6-using-mental-arithmetic-only/3387956#3387956) on binomial distribution.

> Question: Given two independent random variables $X\sim B(n_1,p)$ and $Y\sim B(n_2,p)$ where $n_1<n_2,$ is it true that there exists a random variable $Z\sim (n_2-n_1,p)$ such that $Z$ is independent from $X$?

I know that one can simply take 
$$Z = Y-X$$
and $Z$ is binomially distributed with $n = n_2-n_1$ and probability of success $p.$ 
But I think $Z$ is not independent from $X.$

Comment: Yes, you can just define $Z$ independently of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @Michael How to ensure that $Z$ is independent from $X and $Y$?

Comment: You seem to be asking how to generate a random variable $Z$ with a particular distribution.  There seems to be no connection to $(X,Y)$. Just choose $Z$ independent of $(X,Y)$.

Comment: On a side note: If $X,Y$ are independent then $Y-X$ is not Binomially distributed as you claim, since it can be negative!

Comment: @Michael I forgot to include independence of $X$ and $$.$ Edited.

Comment: Give any family of random variables $\{X_i\}$ and any CDF $F$ we can always find a random variable $Z$ which is independent of $\{X_i\}$ and has CDF $F$. It may be possibile to do this on the same probability space but you can enlarge the space to get such a random variable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you elaborate? Perhaps you could elaborate and type it as an answer.

Comment: No, this is not always possible. Consider a probability space with only $n_2$ elements.

Comment: Idonknow -- the point @Michael is trying to make is that, if $X,Y$ independent and $n_1 < n_2$, then $Y-X<0$ is an event with positive probability, which directly proves that $Z=Y-X$ is not binomial.  Indeed, your intuition that $Z=Y-X$ is binomial perhaps come from a model where the $n_2$ $Y$-flips are indep and the $X$-flips are in fact the first $n_1$ flips in $Y$.  This makes $X,Y$ _dependent_.